# Generating topology in 2 cases

Tags: general-topology

Consider $S=\{ \{0,1 \},\{0,2\} \}$. What is the topological space$ T(S) $generated by  S in the following case ?

1) if $X=\{0,1,2\}$

2) if $X=\{0,1,2,3\}$

For case 1 By definition, S will then be a subbasis of X ,so we can find T(S).

$ T(S)=\{\emptyset ,\{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{0,1,2\}\}$

Now for case 2 , S is not subbase for X,how can we find T(S) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* a subbase in my definition (as all collections of subsets are subbases for some topology..)

Finite intersections are just $\{0,1,2,3\}$ (the empty intersection), $\{0,1\}$ and $\{0,2\}$ (intersections of 1) and $\{0\}$, intersections of 2.

Now take unions of those, we only get $\{0,1,2\}$ as an extra set. Then we have the required topology.

Comment: In my book, S is subbase if union of all elements of S must be, X. But in case 2 the S is not  subbase  because the union of all elements of S is not equal X.

Comment: @amirbahadory Yes, I know. I disagree (I was taught a different definition). In case the union is not $X$, just add $X$ and proceed as before. This will give the right result. We need $X$ in the topology anyway. This is what the empty intersection will give you (by convention)

Comment: It is possible to define a topology generated by F, is the intersection of all topologies containing F. Can we use this ?

Comment: I described this topology in my answer. This algorithm always works, "subbase" or not. So maybe add $X$, then add finite intersections then all unions. Note that $T(S) = T(S\cup\{X\})$ for all $S$.